# Events Calendar Pro doesn't refresh on AJAX loaded pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a scenario when I dynamically have to load parts of the page with AJAX, but some pages have the Events Calendar Pro (wordpress plugin by Modern Tribe), which fails to initialise on dynamic load. Unfortunately I couldn't find any info in their API. I know there is a jQuery event that can receive actions on succesful AJAX, but can't find how to reload the contents of the calendar

This is the script that loads in the AJAX content without page refresh:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "a[target!='_blank']:not(a[href^='#'])", function(e){
    var link = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    jQuery("#content").load( link );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And this is how I could hook in after the AJAX finishes

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
     ...
});
```

Comment: Is the script executed at all on your client-side?

Comment: I just get a spinning loader and messed up layout. The other pages load fine with this method.

Comment: You did not answer my question...

Comment: I don't see much client activity, but I get this error, don't know if it is connected to this issue: WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Comment: This means that your system attempts to establish a WebSocket connection but fails. Maybe the service responsible for WebSocket is down or unreachable for some reason.

Comment: Is that connected with the Events Calendar plugin?

Comment: I do not know. Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178749/discussion-between-gas-and-lajos-arpad).